# What can I do if I'm a level four vampire and even guards come after me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Guards and citizens come after me for being a vampire and I can't sneak into a house or use invisibility without them waking up what do I do

Comment: Do you want to cure your vampirism, or just tips on avoiding being killed?

Comment: I want to cure my vampirism I want to make it so I can no longer be a vampire and be attacks